# Can not cast to boolean from response jaxb java

Tags: java, jaxb

In java 6, i try to get data from a service. IT sometimes return boolean, sometimes string so i made generic response class for string example response:

```
{
    "data": "D",
    "success": true,
    "error": null,
    "validations": null
}
```

bollean:

```
{
    "data": true,
    "success": true,
    "error": null,
    "validations": null
}
```

response class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class BaseResponsefaj<T>{

    private T data;
    private boolean success = true;
    private ExceptionInfo error;
    private List<ValidationInfo> validations;

    public BaseResponsefaj(T data){
        this.data = data;
    }

    public BaseResponsefaj(T data, boolean success){
        this.data = data;
        this.success = success;
    }

    public BaseResponsefaj(){
    }

    public BaseResponsefaj(boolean success, ExceptionInfo error) {
        super();
        this.success = success;
        this.error = error;
    }

    public BaseResponsefaj(boolean success, ExceptionInfo error, T data) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
        this.success = success;
        this.error = error;
    }

    public ExceptionInfo getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public void setError(ExceptionInfo error) {
        this.error = error;
    }

    public List<ValidationInfo> getValidations() {
        return validations;
    }

    public void setValidations(List<ValidationInfo> validations) {
        this.validations = validations;
    }

    public boolean isSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(boolean success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BaseResponse{" +
                "data=" + data +
                ", success=" + success +
                ", error=" + error +
                ", validations=" + validations +
                '}';
    }
}
```

it gets error when try to get ffrom service:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl incompatible with java.lang.String
```

and for also boolean.

this is how i call:

```
    final BaseResponsefaj<?> response;
    ClientResponse getResponse = webResource
         .header("x-api-key", getAhtapotService().getapi())
         .accept("application/json")
         .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
         .get(ClientResponse.class);

                
    final int status = getResponse.getStatus();
            
    if (HttpStatus.SC_OK == status) {
```

until here same for 2 services, string and boolean. after that, i get:

```
response = getResponse.getEntity(BaseResponsefaj.class);
```

and cast to boolean in one service, in other string:

```
(String) response.getData();
```

but it gives error. it is
jersey-bundle-1.19.1.jar to make calls.

I dont want to create 2 response classes for each. in future maybe more types. So generic will be better but i cant fix this. And i dont know if boolean response class also can fix

it gives that error

```
"java.lang.ClassCastException:" org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl"" incompatible" with java.lang.Boolean
```

and sometimes it gives

```
Class has two properties of the same name "data"
```

so i made to this

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class BaseResponseMfaj<T>{

    @XmlElement(required=true)
    private T data;
    
    @XmlTransient
    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }
```

but casting to boolean continues

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl incompatible with java.lang.Boolean
```

and for that

```
Object data = response.getData();
```

prints    data: [data: null]

```
    String stringdata = String.valueOf(response.getData());
```

prints     stringdata: [data: null]

i dont understand why also null for string or object?

```
String booleandata = String.valueOf((Boolean) response.getData());
```

for that gives error

Answer (score 1):

Not good solution but I did like this. Created a root class, removing data from there:

```
public class BaseParametricPrefixResponse {

    private boolean success;
    private ExceptionInfo error;
    private List<ValidationInfo> validations;
}
```

and

```
BooleanParametricPrefixResponse extends BaseParametricPrefixResponse {

    private boolean data;

    public boolean isData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(boolean data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
```

For bollean I created this. I do calls with this and it works. For string I created another. For list string, probably, I need to create another.